# CodeIgniter route issue

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to do something like so: http://domain.com/foo/username and http://domain.com/foo/username/baz but I couldn't figure out how to get it to work using routes.php

Here is what I have in routes.php

```
$route['foo/(:any)'] = foo_controller/index/$1;
$route['foo/(:any)/baz'] = 'foo_controller/baz/$1';
```

Here is my foo_controller.php

```
class Foo_Controller {
    function _construct() {}

    function index() {
        $username = strtolower($this->uri->segment('2'));

        ...
    }

    function baz() {}
}
```

What I get when I go to /foo/username/baz is it just loads the index method.

Help please?

Answer (score 0):

```
$username
```

must be in baz method and route:

```
$route['foo/baz/(:any)'] = 'foo_controller/baz/$1';
```

i think **/foo/username/baz** is wrong uri.

** i'm bad at English.

Answer (score 0):

Switch and use the double quotes:

```
$route['foo/(:any)/baz'] = "foo_controller/baz/$1";
$route['foo/(:any)'] = "foo_controller/index/$1";
```

And the controller methods:

```
function index($username = false) {
     $username = strtolower($username);

    ...
}

function baz($username = false) {
     $username = strtolower($username);

    ...
}
```